# Como remover único container criado com docker-compose

Tags: docker

Tenho um arquivo docker-compose.yml com varias configurações de imagens. Para subir todas posso usar o `docker-compose up -d` e parar `docker-compose down`, se quero subir somente um serviço configurado `docker-compose up -d  nomeDoServico`.

Agora preciso parar somente um serviço configurado, e usando o `docker-compose down nomeDoServico` não funciona. Não queria ficar parando o container, removendo-o e removendo os networks manualmente.

Preciso remover um container, e seus `networks` e inicia-lo novamente, como fazer isso?

Comment: Tentou usar o comando `stop` e `rm`? No seu caso: `docker-compose stop nomeDoServico` e depois `docker-compose rm nomeDoServico`. O `network` só pode ser removido com `down` mesmo, mas talvez você consiga fazer isto depois de usar o `stop` (eu suponho).

Comment: o `docker-compose rm -s -f nomeDoServico` deu certo, obrigado @Dherik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `stop` seguido do `rm` para isto.

Primeiro, pare o serviço com o `stop`:

```
docker-compose stop nomeDoServico
```

Depois, faça a remoção do serviço parado com o `rm`:

```
docker-compose rm nomeDoServico
```

Como apontado pelo próprio autor da pergunta, você pode também usar as opções `-s` e `-f` para parar e forçar a remoção em um único comando:

```
docker-compose -s -f rm nomeDoServico
```